# Mac terminal nw user: how do I start emacs in gui mode? My /Application folder of Mac doesn't have an emacs icon

Tags: osx, start-up

how do I start emacs in gui mode? My /Application folder of Mac doesn't have an emacs icon

I only need gui mode maybe a week, say when editing a html document with inline images.

```
my-silica $ which emacs
/opt/homebrew/bin/emacs
my-silica $ ls /opt/homebrew/bin/emacs | grep emacs
/opt/homebrew/bin/emacs
my-silica $ 
my-silica $ brew info emacs
Warning: Treating emacs as a formula. For the cask, use homebrew/cask/emacs
emacs: stable 27.2 (bottled), HEAD
GNU Emacs text editor
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/emacs/HEAD-19ef864 (4,063 files, 106.4MB) *
  Built from source on 2021-06-07 at 21:49:25
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/emacs.rb
License: GPL-3.0-or-later
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✔
Required: gnutls ✔, jansson ✘
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
To restart emacs after an upgrade:
  brew services restart emacs
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  /opt/homebrew/opt/emacs/bin/emacs --fg-daemon
==> Analytics
install: 22,903 (30 days), 66,997 (90 days), 342,393 (365 days)
install-on-request: 8,669 (30 days), 26,393 (90 days), 144,818 (365 days)
build-error: 7 (30 days)
my-silica $ 
my-silica $ cat ~/.bashrc
# start emacs
function emacs() {
  echo emacsclient -a "" -s "workspace"$(cat ~/.WORKSPACE_INDICATOR) -nw "$@"
  emacsclient -a "" -s "workspace"$(cat ~/.WORKSPACE_INDICATOR) -nw "$@"
}
```

Comment: The standard emacs from homebrew is terminal-only, but the _cask_ version is emacs should work in the gui. You might try `brew uninstall emacs; brew install --cask emacs`. There are also a few other gui versions in homebrew but if you are just using it for a week the standard one is probably the one to try.

Comment: You can download an app at https://emacsformacosx.com.

Comment: @amitp I was on the HEAD version before. would your command downgrade me as a side effect

Comment: Yes, standard brew has non-cask terminal-mode (including HEAD) and stable pre-built binaries gui-mode (since they're pre-built, no HEAD). But it *also* has [this version](https://github.com/d12frosted/homebrew-emacs-plus) which allows for both HEAD and gui. There are other distributions on Mac as well, such as Aquamacs and the "Mac Port" (called [railwaycat](https://github.com/railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport) on homebrew).

Comment: `d12frosted/homebrew-emacs-plus` is quite interesting. 